# Python pandas group non repeating values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Hi I have a data frame which looks like this

```
         col1     col2
    0      A       1
    1      B       2
    2      C       3
    3      A       4
    4      C       5
    5      A       6
```

I would like to groupby and sum for non repeating values in col1 for e.g.

```
A,B,C => 6
A,C => 9
A => 6
```

Is there any way I can do this via pandas functions?

Comment: How is A,B,C == 5 - shouldn't that be 6? And what's the criteria for being a repeat or not?

Comment: Yeah, I have corrected that. It's considered a repeat if it appear again i.e.
if it is A,B,C,A =>

ABC is one group and A is another group

Comment: What if row 4 is a `D`? are you going to group it with the first `A,B,C` (rows 0,1,2)?

Comment: Yes, if row 4 is D then it would be group with the first i.e A,B,C,D  since it's not repeated i.e does not appear before  (which is just A,B,C before it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, you could create groups using `groupby` + `cumcount` (where the nth occurrences of each `col1` value will be grouped the same); then groupby the groups and `join` "col1"s and `sum` "col2"s:

```
out = df.groupby(df.groupby('col1').cumcount()).agg({'col1':','.join, 'col2':'sum'})
```

Output:

```
    col1  col2
0  A,B,C     6
1    A,C     9
2      A     6
```

Comment: Sorry, just to add on. Would this still work if the values in col1 is random? i.e. instead of A in the last row, I have B

Comment: @Ruster if the rule is to group values on the order they appear in the column, it should work.